# Integral of a function not defined at all points

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

$$\int_0^l{\dfrac{2\sin^3\left(\frac{{\pi}x}{l}\right)\sin\left(\frac{{\pi}nx}{l}\right)}{l}dx} = \dfrac{12\sin\left({\pi}n\right)}{{\pi}\left(n^4-10n^2+9\right)}$$

But this function is not defined at $n = 1$ and $n = 3$. Why does this happen even though I integrated it for all $n$. This also clearly has an integral defined if we substitute $n = 1$ before  integrating.

[link to the steps while integrating. Its an online integral calculator](https://www.integral-calculator.com/#expr=2%2Flsin%5E%283%29%28pi%2Ax%2Fl%29%2Asin%28n%2Api%2Ax%2Fl%29&lbound=0&ubound=l)

Comment: Are you missing the variable of integration?

Comment: Show us your development and we will tell you where the "for all $n$" claim is invalidated.

Comment: What did you mean by definition? Is it the steps I used to reach at this answer?

Comment: @YvesDaoust I have added the link for calculation steps

Comment: if you take a look at the steps, you'll see that there are several substitutions that won't work for particular values of $n$ (i.e.$v=(n+3)u$ does not work for $n=-3$). That's why you can't use this formula for $n=-3, -1, 1, 3$.

Comment: @Allen: I see. You cannot trust this integrator blindly.

Comment: Oh I see now. But why do things like these happen

Answer (score 0):

You are probably trapped by a case similar to

$$I_m=-\int_0^{2\pi}\cos mx\,dx=\left.\frac{\sin mx}m\right|_0^{2\pi}=\frac{\sin2\pi m}m,$$

believing that it is established "for all $m$".

The final expression is indeed undefined for $m=0$ because the integrand degenerates to $1$ and the antiderivative doesn't hold.

Comment: Why does the antiderivative not hold. Is it because we are wrongly picking the antiderivative

Comment: @Allen: this is obvious. Set $m=0$.

Comment: Yes it is obvious that the final expression is not defined. But why does this happen, shouldn't the antiderivatiive define it at all points

Comment: @Allen Not for all values of parameters. Consider the antiderivative $\frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}$ of $x^n$. Why does not it work for $n=-1$?

Comment: @Allen: by virtue of what principle should it ?

Comment: @Yves Daoust OK I get the point. You are saying that there is no constraint that it should exist. Right?

Comment: @allen: no I am asking a question, which you didn't answer.

Comment: Well because we in the beginning derived $x^{(n+1)}/{(n+1)}$ for $n > 1$